# ifame matching with inserting page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
<iframe id="payframe" src="~" width="100%" height="3000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="scroll(0, 0);"></iframe>
```

my current `iframe` code is like above. its height is set as 3000 not along the content. To fix this and match with content length, in my `HTML` page which will be inserted in to `iframe`, I wrote like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            autoResize();
        });

        function autoResize(){
            var newheight;
            var newwidth;

            newheight = document.getElementById("register_apply").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

            parent.document.getElementById("register_apply").height = (newheight) + "px";
        }
```

register_apply is the id for the wrapper, which contains all content. After making iframe height 0 I tried but it doesn't work. Is there any that I have to modify?

Comment: You are trying to change the height of the `iframe` right?

Comment: oh. the id there should be `iframe` id right?

Comment: Yeah it probably should be.

Comment: then for height is it okay to set as 0? since even though I changed id, it doesn't seem work

Comment: It would be better if you included the whole code in your question or maybe a demo in jsfiddle or the built-in code viewer  of stackoverflow.